# Yii2 testing when using blameable behavior

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model using `Blameable` behavior:

```
class Vehicle extends ActiveRecord 
{
    // ...
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'blameable' => [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                'createdByAttribute' => 'UserID',
                'updatedByAttribute' => null,
            ]
        ];
    }
    // ...
}
```

The problem is when I try to save an instance of `Vehicle` for testing with specific UserID, `Blameable` will override that with null (as no user is set to be the current logged in) and save of the model would fail.

This snipped illustrates how I've been solving this so far:

```
$owner = $this->createUser(); // creates user with fake data
Yii::$app->user->setIdentity($owner);
$vehicle = $this->createVehicle(); // creates vehicle and relies that the $owner->UserID will be set when vehicle is being saved
```

However I don't like it because it's not obvious why the user identity is being set before hand. Is there a way to disable the `Blameable` behavior in testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just detach the BlamableBehavior in your `createVehicle()` method as follows:

```
public function createVehile()
{
    $vehicle = new Vehicle();
    $vehicle->detachBehavior('blameable');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In my case, using the same `BlameableBehavior` as @ddinchev I needed detached all using `detachBehaviors();` to work. maybe the name 'blameable' does not work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Detaching the behavior wont solve the issue for those using `'value' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username` since calling new Model will still throw an error.

Instead you can use the _before method to set the identity for all the tests.

**unit test**

```php
use app\models\User; // your user class


class SupplierTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    protected function _before()
    {
        // Required for model blameable behavior using Yii@.
        $owner = new User(); 
        $owner->username = 'tester';
        $owner->auth_key = '123456';
        $owner->password_hash = '123456';
        $owner->email = 'something@some.com';
        $owner->save();
        Yii::$app->user->setIdentity($owner);   
    }

    public function testCreateRecord() {
        $rec = new Supplier();
        $rec->supplier = "Supplier ABC";
        $rec->smr_number = "123456";
        $rec->validate();
        Debug::debug($rec->getErrors());
        $this->assertTrue($rec->save());
    }
```

**various model behaviors**

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => \yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior::className(),
                'value' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
            ],
            [
                'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'sammaye\audittrail\LoggableBehavior',
                'userAttribute' => 'updated_by', //blameable attribute of the current model.
                'ignored' => ['updated_by', 'updated_at'], // This ignores fields from a selection of all fields, not needed with allowed
            ],
        ];
    }
```